# Factor fully $625-(y-2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

So far, I have used $(y-2)$ twice (multiplying both) because of the exponent being $2$. But, I need to factor and that's when I get confused. Please help!

Comment: $625=25^2$, and $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Comment: $$625-(y-2)^2=25^2-(y-2)^2=(27-y)(23+y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember the difference of squares formula:
$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
Our expression $625-(y-2)^2$ can be rewritten as:
$$25^2-(y-2)^2$$
Set $a=25$ and $b=y-2$. Our expression can be factored as:
$$(25+(y-2))(25-(y-2))$$
$$=(y+23)(27-y)$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{625-(y-2)^2=(y+23)(27-y)}$$

Answer (score -2):

Note that $625 - (y - 2)^2 = 25^2 - (y - 2)^2$. Let $z = y - 2$. Then
$$625 - (y - 2)^2 = 25^2 - z^2 = (25 - z)(25 + z),$$
so
$$625 - (y - 2)^2 = (25 - (y - 2))(25 + (y - 2)) = (27 - y)(23 + y).$$

Comment: The second factor should be $25+(y-2)=23+y$

Comment: Who downvoted my answer? It was obviously a typo. Of course the second factor should be $25 + (y - 2) = 23 + y$. Next time just leave a comment.